# SVN confusion in switching process from trunk to branch

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am having a confusion in switching from trunk to branch .Here are my points-
    1-Suppose I made some changes in trunk and committed the code from trunk.
      One of my coworkers working copy was trunk and he switches to branch. Will he get my committed code in his branch.
    2-Suppose my working copy was trunk and I made some changes in code and did not committed.After that I Switches to branch what will happen to my uncommitted code and will it reflect in my branch copy.
    please explain each case separately`enter code here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you take a branch in SVN, that code becomes separate from trunk (and any other branch you may have).  This means if you make a change to your trunk code and commit it, it only affects trunk, and if you make a change in the branch and commit it, it only affects the branch.

If someone else is working with trunk, then when you commit to trunk and they update, they'll see your changes.  If they're working with branch, and you commit to trunk, they won't get your changes when they update.

Comment: one more thing I want to ask If my working copy is trunk and some other developer has committed code of branch and now I switch to branch(I have not updated the branch) I get the committed code of branch of other developer  is this a normal behaviour.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would think that you would get everything that had changed in the branch.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response .Can u please tell me how to check for currently  working copy .